# What's the best way to level after you get into the Outlands?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So, recently I got my Undead warrior to the Outlands. I thought it was great to be in the other planet of WoW. I was ready to power level up to around 70 to get back to Northrend. But it seems like leveling in the Outlands (especially Zangarmash) takes a LONG time. I cant use Refer a Friend because none of my friends play WoW. If all other hope is lost I'll resort to dungeoning. Any hints out there?

Comment: "Resort to dungeoning"?  If you're a warrior, pick up some tank gear, and LFG.  No queue time, it levels you _crazy_ fast, and you get awesome gear.  (When WotLK came out, I leveled my tauren warrior from 16 to 70 entirely in dungeons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I recently ran Outlands on my DK I breezed through **Hellfire Peninsula** quests, following that line all over the place until I could move onto **Terrokar Forest**. I did **Terrokar Forest** and moved left into **Nagrand** until I was able to fly north to the **Netherstorm**. Bombed through that for a few levels until I could hit **Northrend**.

I know you didn't ask, but, once in **Northrend** I slid from Left-to-Right, **Borean Tundra to Dragonblight to Zul'Drak, then north into Stormpeaks on back left to Icecrown**.

If you're not a tank, then while you're running your quests be sure to always queue for random dungeons so you get that bonus XP. If you're tank, you usually get an instant-queue hit and it can take longer to level via dungeons (since you can only do the dungeon quests once per dungeon per toon) and you'll spend more time in dungeons than getting quests done.

Answer (score 2):

Questing is always the best way to level, especially without Refer a Friend's bonus giving you more xp for kills.  Just follow the quests progressions through Burning Crusade content and you'll be of the proper level to head to Northrend after like 3 zones.

Also if you already have the means to do so, getting heirloom gear is a great boost to leveling as well.

Answer (score 2):

With heirlooms I generally do all the quests in Hellfire and then dungeon my way the rest of the way to level 68 - at level 68 you can begin queuing for WotLK dungeons which grant significantly more experience.

With a full set of heirlooms you should be most of the way to level 68 by the time you finish the quests in Hellfire.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is over a year old, so this comment is just some quick bullet points for leveling in Outlands as of patch 6.2.2. This comment is directed towards players who are only interested in leveling as QUICKLY as possible.

•Secure flight training as SOON as you hit level 60. Same for Northrend with Cold Weather Flying, and Pandaria with Wisdom of the Four Winds. This is going to more than double (I'd almost go as far to say triple) your questing rate. Plus you don't have to worry about killing a bunch of useless mobs that you are bound to aggro on a ground mount.

•Heirlooms are still your best friend. With the XP stacking with the more pieces you have, it will give you an unparalleled boost in XP gains per quest, dungeon, or even just a regular mob kill.

•If you haven't done so already, get yourself into a guild. Doesn't even have to be a good one, as long as the guild is level 25. You will get a slew of helpful abilities (mass resurrection, shorter cooldown on hearth stone, portable bank, and even allows access to pieces of heirloom gear otherwise unobtainable without being in a guild). If you aren't like me (I took the first G-invite I got from a level 25 guild), you most likely can find a fun "leveling guild" that will help you with quests, dungeons, and even have done people to share your victories with!

•Professions. If you're looking to power level to max level in a hurry, leveling your professions will slow you down more than you think (some may disagree but meh, I digress). For example, if you have good momentum going thru quests and you stop to mine or gather every ore or flower you see, it will kill your momentum instantaneously. If you have a main that is decently wealthy, you can always just buy mats at the auction house and power level your professions later on.

•As entertaining and delightful world events can be (ie. Brewfest, Winter's Veil, Midsummer Fire Festival), try to refrain from getting involved with the enticing activities. You won't get much from them, aside from a few pieces of gold and a couple achievements. Not really worth your time while trying to speed level.

•If you are questing as a DPS, then queue for random dungeons as a DPS. If you want to waste time switching specs every time you want to run an instance, then be my guest. Personally, I'd rather sacrifice the shorter queue times in exchange for being able to continue blasting thru quests while waiting for a group invite.

•Remember it's just a game and it's meant for you to have FUN! I lost sight of that notion back in WotLK while power leveling 8 characters to max level, and all I ended up with was just that. 8 characters at max level, and no really great memories of leveling any of them. If you can find friends to quest with, or run dungeons with, it'll make the leveling experience (even the power leveling experience) a lot more memorable and noteworthy.

•Finally, I would recommend having a reason in mind as to WHY you are leveling your toon. If you're leveling it just to level it, you're most likely going to lose interest in it. Set some long term goals like eventually queuing up for raids, or gearing up for some pvp action, or like me, to get your toon at max level in preparation for the next expansion. Having a real reason to level, along with some solid goals, will help keep you focused on continuing the grind to max level. The next time you feel like you're staying to get bored, think slot those things for a moment, and see if it doesn't give you a bit of encouragement!

That's all for me guys and gals. I know this was a bit lengthy but I wanted to cover a lot of ground since this post hadn't been updated in a while. Hope you all are having a wonderful day, and I wish each of you the best of luck on all your future leveling adventures!

-S

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the Questline of Burning Crusade, and additionally do some dungeons once, because the quests are a big boost in EXP.

Additionally you should consider to stay in lower level areas until the quests are green, because the quests will be significantly easier to do if they are not on the same level as you are, which results in a lot faster questing time.

Answer (score 0):

The TourGuide addon http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/tourguide hasn't been updated in years, but all its data for Ouland are still completely up to date. It will point you in a nearly optimal path to completing the quests in a minimal amount of time. If you have the TomTom addon as well it will put up a big arrow on your screen pointing exactly where to go to acquire or complete the quest quest in the list.

Also make sure you learn flying as soon as you hit 60 to minimize travel times.

Finally, you can get a huge amount of experience from doing a single ramparts and a single blood furnace instance. They each have multiple quests that turn in for a nice chunk of XP. I typically go from 58-65 in Hellfire alone between all the quests and those two instance runs.